# Grails 3 - forward with filtered params

Tags: grails, parameters, forward, grails-controller

In my Grails 3 *controller* have two *actions*

```
def one() {
    forward([ action: 'two', params: [ a: 3 ] ])
}

def two() {
    println params
}
```

When I call `/myController/one?a=1`, the printed params are

```
[a:[3, 1], controller:myController, action:two]
```

Said that I was somehow surprised of this outcome, I proceeded by changing the `one` action as follows

```
def one() {
    params.remove('a')
    println params
    forward([ action: 'two', params: [ a: 3 ] ])
}
```

The two `println`s combined showed

```
[controller:myController, action:one]
[a:[3, 1], controller:myController, action:two]
```

with the latter again includign both the original `a` parameter's value and the new custom value.

My question is: is there something I can do to get rid of the original value, without putting ugly workarounds in place (like using a different name for my param)?

Comment: See the discussion at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10231

Comment: Thanks for the input! After digging a bit deeper among Grails issues I found the anwer to my question (below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess [this comment](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9539#issuecomment-170868902) from Graeme Rocher settles any doubts about the overall feasibility:

> A forward is supposed to forward all of the origin params [...]
>
> However there is no way with the way current servlets work to "override" a parameter, the originals are always retained on a forward.